# Updating a binary tree using a pointer

Tags: swift, pointers, data-structures, closures, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to update a self-balancing binary tree.  Normally, you can update it by 1) searching a node, 2) deleting it, 3) and inserting the tree with a new node.  But, I want to see if this is possible simply by retaining a pointer to a node from the first step and updating it so that I can bypass the deletion and insertion and improve the time complexity, especially when it comes to a large number of nodes.

The tree itself is standard binary search tree.

```swift
public class TreeNode<T: Comparable>: Equatable {
    public typealias Node = TreeNode<T>
    
    var key: T?
    var leftChild: Node?
    var rightChild: Node?
    fileprivate weak var parent: Node?
    
    var isNullLeaf: Bool {
        return key == nil && isLeaf
    }
    
    var isLeaf: Bool {
        return rightChild == nil && leftChild == nil
    }
    
    public init(key: T?, leftChild: Node?, rightChild: Node?, parent: Node?) {
        self.key = key
        self.leftChild = leftChild
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.leftChild?.parent = self
        self.rightChild?.parent = self
    }
    
    /// Null leaf
    public convenience init() {
        self.init(key: nil, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil, parent: nil)
    }
    
    static public func == <T>(lhs: TreeNode<T>, rhs: TreeNode<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}

public final class Tree<T: Comparable> {
    public typealias Node = TreeNode<T>
    
    fileprivate(set) var root: Node
    fileprivate let nullLeaf = Node()
    
    public init() {
        root = nullLeaf
    }
    
    func search(key: T, f: (inout Node) -> Void) {
        search(key: key, node: &root, f:  f)
    }

    fileprivate func search(key: T, node: inout Node, f: (inout Node) -> Void) {
        if !node.isNullLeaf {
            if let nodeKey = node.key {
                /// When a node is found, pass by reference as an argument to a closure so that it retains the connection to the node when it's being update.
                if key == nodeKey {
                    f(&node)
                } else if key < nodeKey {
                    guard node.leftChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.leftChild!, f: f)
                } else {
                    guard node.rightChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.rightChild!, f: f)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public func insert(key: T) {
       /// insertion logic
    }
    
    /// Other operations
}
```

My idea was to search the tree through recursion and when a node is found, pass it as an argument to a closure function, which will ultimately be called to update the node.  Also, the found node would be pass by reference.

```swift
class Test<T: Comparable> {
    private(set) var tree = Tree<T>()
    
    func insert(key: T) {
        tree.insert(key: key)
    }
    
    func update(for node: T, with newNode: T) {
        tree.search(key: node) { foundNode in
            foundNode.key = newNode
        }
    }
}

let test = Test<MyNode>()
let node = MyNode()
let anotherNode = MyNode()
test.insert(key: node)
test.update(for: node, with: anotherNode)
```

The problem is the update doesn't happen.  If I search for newly updated node in the tree, it doesn't exist.

**Update**

Above code is a modified version of a [Red-Black tree](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Red-Black%20Tree/RedBlackTree.swift), specifically modifying the search method to use a pointer instead.

I've tried my idea on a simplified version of a binary search tree below and it seems to be updating the value of a specified node.

```swift
public final class BinaryTree<T: Comparable> {
    public final class Node<T> {
        public var value: T
        public var leftChild: Node<T>?
        public var rightChild: Node<T>?
        
        public init(value: T, leftChild: Node<T>? = nil, rightChild: Node<T>? = nil) {
            self.value = value
            self.leftChild = leftChild
            self.rightChild = rightChild
        }
    }
    
    public var rootNode: Node<T>
    
    public init(rootNode: Node<T>) {
        self.rootNode = rootNode
    }
    
    public func addNodes(to parent: Node<T>, leftChild: Node<T>?, rightChild: Node<T>?) {
        parent.leftChild = leftChild
        parent.rightChild = rightChild
    }
    
    public func searchTree(_ value: T, node: inout Node<T>?, f: (inout Node<T>?) -> Void) {
        if node == nil || value == node?.value {
            f(&node)
        } else if value < node!.value {
            searchTree(value, node: &node!.leftChild, f: f)
        } else {
            searchTree(value, node: &node!.rightChild, f: f)
        }
    }
}
```

Tested here.

```swift
var rootNode: BinaryTree<Int>.Node<Int>? = BinaryTree<Int>.Node(value: 100, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil)
let tree = BinaryTree(rootNode: rootNode!)

/// add new nodes. This is not a self-balancing tree so the left child's value has to be smaller than the parent and the right child's value greater than the parent.
let leftChild = BinaryTree<Int>.Node(value: 0, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil)
let rightChild = BinaryTree<Int>.Node(value: 200, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil)
tree.addNodes(to: rootNode!, leftChild: leftChild, rightChild: rightChild)

/// the node argument is the starting point of the search so let's start from the root node.
/// the found node will be updated with a new node with a value 50
tree.searchTree(0, node: &rootNode) { foundNode in
    let newNode = BinaryTree<Int>.Node(value: 50, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil)
    foundNode = newNode
}

/// The node with a value as 0 is now gone.
tree.searchTree(0, node: &rootNode) { foundNode in
    print(foundNode) /// nil
}

/// The node has bee properly updated.
tree.searchTree(50, node: &rootNode) { foundNode in
    print(foundNode) /// node with 50 as the value found
}
```

But can't seem to figure out why the original code isn't updating a node by pointer.

Comment: Have you debugged the code, do you have any hunch where the problem might be?

Comment: Please could you add your insert function as well so we can rule out anything going wrong there

Comment: I've updated my question. The original code I'm trying to troubleshoot is a Red-Black tree from [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Red-Black%20Tree/RedBlackTree.swift).  I've tried my attempt with a simplified version of a binary tree and it seems to working so I'm not quite sure what's wrong with the original one.

Comment: @Kevvv - when I tried your original code with my own insert function it worked by removing `root = nullLeaf` in the `init` - this was causing your `search` function to fail because it never went past this condition `if let nodeKey = node.key` because since `root` was assigned to `nullLeaf` it's key is `null`. Just commenting that line out and making root an optional worked for me with your original code. Anyways, you found a solution so nvm ;)

Comment: @ShawnFrank hey thanks for the tip. I was actually just trying my idea on a simplified version which seems to be working, but I still can't seem to get the original code to work. Do you mind posting your code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the main issue as I mentioned in the comments was with these line of code

```
fileprivate(set) var root: Node
    fileprivate let nullLeaf = Node()
    
    public init() {
        root = nullLeaf
    }
```

Root is currently pointing to a `nullLeaf` which has the following properties:

```
key = nil
leftChild = nil
self.rightChild = nil
self.parent = nil
```

I wasn't sure how your insert function was implemented but when I used my insert implementation, this updated the root's properties to the following:

```
key = nil
leftChild = node
self.rightChild = nil
self.parent = nil
```

Now when you run your `search` function which starts at the root:

```
func search(key: T, f: (inout Node) -> Void) {
        search(key: key, node: &root, f:  f)
    }

    fileprivate func search(key: T, node: inout Node, f: (inout Node) -> Void) {
        if !node.isNullLeaf {
            if let nodeKey = node.key {
                /// When a node is found, pass by reference as an
                /// argument to a closure so that it retains the 
                /// connection to the node when it's being update.
                if key == nodeKey {
                    f(&node)
                } else if key < nodeKey {
                    guard node.leftChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.leftChild!, f: f)
                } else {
                    guard node.rightChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.rightChild!, f: f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`if let nodeKey = node.key {` is false based on the above root attributes and so it does go into your block where the logic and completion handler gets executed.

**Changes and Implementation**

Since your main question to answer is

> But can't seem to figure out why the original code isn't updating a
> node by pointer.

I am using my insertion implementation of a Binary Search Tree even though you mentioned Binary Tree as the main purpose is to show the pointer working.

Here is what I updated to your code:

TreeNode - no changes to your code

```
// No change to your original code
public class TreeNode<T: Comparable>: Equatable {
    public typealias Node = TreeNode<T>
    
    var key: T?
    var leftChild: Node?
    var rightChild: Node?
    fileprivate weak var parent: Node?
    
    var isNullLeaf: Bool {
        return key == nil && isLeaf
    }
    
    var isLeaf: Bool {
        return rightChild == nil && leftChild == nil
    }
    
    public init(key: T?, leftChild: Node?, rightChild: Node?, parent: Node?) {
        self.key = key
        self.leftChild = leftChild
        self.rightChild = rightChild
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.leftChild?.parent = self
        self.rightChild?.parent = self
    }
    
    /// Null leaf
    public convenience init() {
        self.init(key: nil, leftChild: nil, rightChild: nil, parent: nil)
    }
    
    static public func == <T>(lhs: TreeNode<T>, rhs: TreeNode<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}
```

Tree - minor changes and some additions, I have added comments

```
public final class Tree<T: Comparable> {
    public typealias Node = TreeNode<T>
    
    // root starts off as nil
    fileprivate(set) var root: Node?
    
    // I don't make use of this
    //fileprivate let nullLeaf = Node()
    
    // No initialization of root
    public init() {
        //root = nullLeaf
    }
    
    // No change to your code except to safely evaluate root
    func search(key: T, f: (inout Node) -> Void) {
        if var root = root {
            search(key: key, node: &root, f:  f)
        }
    }
    
    // No change to your code here
    fileprivate func search(key: T, node: inout Node, f: (inout Node) -> Void)
    {
        if !node.isNullLeaf {
            if let nodeKey = node.key {
                /// When a node is found, pass by reference as an argument
                /// to a closure so that it retains the connection to the node
                /// when it's being update.
                if key == nodeKey {
                    f(&node)
                } else if key < nodeKey {
                    guard node.leftChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.leftChild!, f: f)
                } else {
                    guard node.rightChild != nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    search(key: key, node: &node.rightChild!, f: f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // My insert implementation
    public func insert(key: T) {
        if let root = insertInternal(key, currentNode: root)
        {
            self.root = root
        }
    }
    
    // My insert recursion implementation
    private func insertInternal(_ data: T, currentNode: Node?) -> Node?
    {
        if currentNode == nil
        {
            let newNode = Node()
            newNode.key = data
            return newNode
        }
        
        if let currentData = currentNode?.key, data > currentData
        {
            currentNode?.rightChild
                = insertInternal(data, currentNode: currentNode?.rightChild)
            return currentNode
        }
        
        currentNode?.leftChild
            = insertInternal(data, currentNode: currentNode?.leftChild)
        
        return currentNode
    }
    
    // My implementation ofLevel order / Breadth first traversal
    // to display values
    func printLevelOrder()
    {
        print("\n** PRINTING BST IN LEVEL ORDER (BFS) ** ")
        
        var queue: [Node] = []
        
        if let root = root
        {
            queue.append(root)
        }
        
        while !queue.isEmpty
        {
            let currentNode = queue.removeFirst()
            
            if let currentData = currentNode.key
            {
                print(currentData)
                
                if let left = currentNode.leftChild
                {
                    queue.append(left)
                }
                
                if let right = currentNode.rightChild
                {
                    queue.append(right)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Test class - no much changes

```
// No change to your code here except display function
class Test<T: Comparable> {
    private(set) var tree = Tree<T>()
    
    func insert(key: T) {
        tree.insert(key: key)
    }
    
    func update(for node: T, with newNode: T) {
        tree.search(key: node) { foundNode in
            foundNode.key = newNode
        }
    }
    
    // Just added a display
    func display() {
        tree.printLevelOrder()
    }
}
```

Finally here is the main

**Test 1 - simple with 1 node**

```
print("Test 1")
var test = Test<Int>()
print("Inserting 10")
test.insert(key: 10)
print("Updating 10 with 8")
test.update(for: 10, with: 8)
test.display()
```

Output

```
Test 1
Inserting 10
Updating 10 with 8

** PRINTING BST IN LEVEL ORDER (BFS) ** 
8
```

As you can see the exchange of values has happened successfully with the pointer

**Test 2 - a little more complex tree with many nodes**

```
print("\n\nTest 2")
test = Test<Int>()
print("Inserting 5")
test.insert(key: 5)
print("Inserting 11")
test.insert(key: 11)
print("Inserting 4")
test.insert(key: 4)
print("Inserting 7")
test.insert(key: 7)
print("Inserting 17")
test.insert(key: 17)
print("Current tree before update")
test.display()
```

This should give us a binary search tree like this:

[image: Binary Search Tree Swift Insert Search Binary Tree Pointer]

And printing the BFS traversal shows us this:

```
Test 2
Inserting 5
Inserting 11
Inserting 4
Inserting 7
Inserting 17
Current tree before update

** PRINTING BST IN LEVEL ORDER (BFS) ** 
5
4
11
7
17
```

Now Let's try to change the value of 7 with 16 which is done with the pointer

```
print("Updating 7 with 16")
test.update(for: 7, with: 16)
print("Current tree after update")
test.display()
```

The output is as expected with the value of 7 and swapped with 16

```
Updating 7 with 16
Current tree after update

** PRINTING BST IN LEVEL ORDER (BFS) ** 
5
4
11
16
17
```

Ofcourse, after this swap, the tree is no longer a Binary Search Tree but I think you can see the pointer working well with the above tweaks.

Comment: Greatly appreciated!!